# Difference between @cuda.jit and @jit(target='gpu')

Tags: cuda, numba

I have a question on working with Python CUDA libraries from Continuum's Accelerate and numba packages. Is using the decorator `@jit` with `target = gpu` the same as `@cuda.jit`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they are not the same, although the eventual compilation path into PTX into assembler is. The `@jit` decorator is the general compiler path, which can be optionally steered onto a CUDA device. The `@cuda.jit` decorator is effectively the low level Python CUDA kernel dialect which Continuum Analytics have developed. So you get support for CUDA built-in variables like `threadIdx` and memory space specifiers like `__shared__` in `@cuda.jit`.

If you want to write a CUDA kernel in Python and compile and run it, use `@cuda.jit`. Otherwise, if you want to accelerate an existing piece of Python use `@jit` with a CUDA target.