# 'Cannot determine Numba type' error on CuPy data

Tags: python-3.x, numba, cupy

I am trying to process some data, produced by CuPy logic, with Numba code. But getting different errors. For example for simplified example

```
import cupy as cp
import numba
from numba import void, int32, int64, float32, float64
import numpy as np

@numba.jit
def numba_test(a, b, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            a[i, j] += b[i, j]

a = cp.zeros((100, 10), dtype=np.float32)
b = cp.zeros((100, 10), dtype=np.float32)
numba_test(a, b, 100, 10)
```

I'm getting

```
<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>:6: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "numba_test" failed type inference due to: non-precise type pyobject
[1] During: typing of argument at <ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff> (8)

File "<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>", line 8:
def numba_test(a, b, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
    ^

  @numba.jit
<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>:6: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "numba_test" failed type inference due to: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>

File "<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>", line 8:
def numba_test(a, b, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
    ^

  @numba.jit
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/object_mode_passes.py:178: NumbaWarning: Function "numba_test" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True, but has lifted loops.

File "<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>", line 8:
def numba_test(a, b, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
    ^

  state.func_ir.loc))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/object_mode_passes.py:188: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>", line 8:
def numba_test(a, b, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
    ^

  state.func_ir.loc))
<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>:6: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "numba_test" failed type inference due to: non-precise type pyobject
[1] During: typing of argument at <ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff> (8)

File "<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>", line 8:
def numba_test(a, b, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
    ^

  @numba.jit
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/object_mode_passes.py:178: NumbaWarning: Function "numba_test" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True.

File "<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>", line 8:
def numba_test(a, b, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
    ^

  state.func_ir.loc))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/object_mode_passes.py:188: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "<ipython-input-1-d30521cb61ff>", line 8:
def numba_test(a, b, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
    ^

  state.func_ir.loc))
```

I am running the code on Google Colab, was able to run some CuPy code and considerable amount of Numba code before.

Adding (void(float64[:, :], float64[:, :], int64, int64)) after @numba.jit doesn't help, generating error like invalid argument type pyObject. Replacing a and b with cp.asarray(a) don't help too. How to run this?

Developers write they provide necessary interface https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/interoperability.html

```
@cuda.jit
def add(x, out):
        start = cuda.grid(1)
        stride = cuda.gridsize(1)
        for i in range(start, x.shape[0], stride):
                out[i] = x[i] + 2

a = cupy.arange(10)
out = cupy.zeros_like(a)

add[1, 32](a, out)
```

works

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the CPU JIT compiler. You should follow the instruction pages that you linked, and do

```
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit
def ...
```

to use the CUDA JIT compiler.

Comment: I think you are not right, there is target='cuda' in @ numba.jit and @ numba.vectorize. Don't see clear evidence in documentation and can't re-check now, but at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890045/difference-between-cuda-jit-and-jittarget-gpu

Comment: Please re-read the docs you found, the other SO question you linked, give the suggested change a try, and report back.

Comment: What I see is that there is a way with @ cuda.jit. But it requires low-level programming through all these cuda.threadIdx and thread per block. With @ jit the code is simpler and there is a hope that compiler will generate most effective code and settings for each given architecture